# char pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I am trying to see to get around pointer to pointers. I am confused with this

```
int syntax_error(int num) {
   cout << num << endl;
   static char *err[] = {
        "Cannot open\n",
        "I can open\n",
        "Sorry\n",
        "Thank you\n"
    　};

    printf("%s", err[num]);

    cout<<"&err[num][1]"<<" "<<&err[num][1]<<endl;
    cout<<"&err[num]"<<" "<<&err[num]<<endl;
    cout<<"err[num][1]"<<" "<<err[num][1]<<endl;
    cout<<"*err[num]"<<" "<<*err[num]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Say num = 3. Then the following outputs were produced

```
   Thank you
   &err[num][1] hank you
   &err[num] 0x8049ca4
   err[num][1] h
   *err[num] T
```

I read that the `&` operator refers to the address of the pointer to which it refers to. Here should it not return the address of err[num][1] rather than what is stored from there till end. On the other hand, `&[num]` is returning the address. I am confused here. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help.

Question re edited:
 `&` operator should refer to the address. So `&err[num][1]` should return an address. Here it gave the string starting from `err[3][1]`. On the other hand `&err[num]` returns an address. So why this mix up

Comment: Please reframe your question !

Comment: Actually, when `num` is 2, `printf("%s", err[num]);` will print `Sorry` not `Thank you`.

Comment: @AnnieKim I am sorry. I meant num = 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` is not a standalone operator, it is defined as follows:

`a[b] == *(a + b)`

If you rewrite the expressions you will quickly start to understand what is happening:

`&err[num][1] == &(*(*(err + num) + 1)) == *(err + num) + 1`

This is `char *` pointer pointing to the second character in the specific string.

`&err[num] == &(*(err + num)) == err + num`

This is `char **` pointer pointing into the outer array.

`cout` knows how to print a C string `char*` but not a `char**` pointer, so it just prints the pointer value.

Note: it's generally a bad idea to mix C and C++ I/O.

Comment: Thanks alot. just a question more. So how will I output the  `char **` pointer which points into the outer array?

Comment: @Vaidyanathan Well, that depends on what you want to output. There is no reasonable semantic for printing a `char **` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a `char *` to `op<<`, it assumes it's a C-style string and acts accordingly. The address of the second character in a C-style string is no different to the address of the first, in terms of its backing type - it's still a `char *`.

If you really want the pointer itself, cast it to a `void *` so that it doesn't know what the underlying type is.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main (void) {
    const char *name = "=paxdiablo";
    std::cout << name << ' ' << (void*)name << '\n';
    std::cout << &name[1] << "  " << (void*)&(name[1]) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
=paxdiablo 0x8048880
paxdiablo  0x8048881
```